# Managing floating point precision - Best practices?

Tags: python, pandas

What are the best practices for managing floating point precision in Python / Pandas?

The classic example is that

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3], 'b': [0.1], 'c': [0.3]})
df['a'] * df['b'] - df['c']
```

yields

```
0    5.55111512e-17
dtype: float64
```

but I have not yet found recommendations on how to manage this type of issue.

Currently, my workaround is to round the results to 10 decimal places but this feels clunky.

Is there a better dtype I could be using? Or should I be more careful about the precision of every column of floats which is being held within my model?

---

So the *question* is:
Is there a way to perform the calculation `df['a'] * df['b'] - df['c']` such that it yields `0`?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you want to "manage" them? What do you want to do here? Check if the answer is near zero? We have ways of doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by _manage_?  What actual operation are you performing?  Are you actually asking "How can I display floating point values with uniform precision"?  Or are you asking "How can I compare two floating point values to determine equality"?  Or something else?

Comment: I think what I am asking is:
Is there a way to perform the calculation 
`df['a'] * df['b'] - df['c']` such that it yields 0?

Comment: (1) Use exact `Decimal` arithmetic; (2) round the result; (3) check for being *close* to 0.00, instead of *exactly** that value.  All three are well documented on line.

Comment: I was caught out by floating point precision because the code I was running effectively calculated
`df['a'] * df['b] / df['b]`

I expected the result to be `df['a']` and only realised much further down the line that it was not.

Could I have done anything to prevent this or must I always round the result of any float arithmetic to a number of decimal places?

Comment: In that case `np.isclose(df['a'], df['a'] * df['b] / df['b])` would be all True.